# What is causing my LEXUS RX 300 Automatic gearbox failure?

Tags: automatic-transmission, lexus, rx300

My Lexus RX 300 automatic gearbox died and I tried to replace it with several new gearboxes that I bought but it is not working. The car may move for 5 minutes then stop. May you help me?

Is it my mechanic who bought the wrong gearbox (I live in Africa)? If so how do I make sure I buy the right gearbox for my car model?

Comment: Have you checked to ensure the new transmission is topped off with transmission fluid? Also, what year is your RX300?